Is it possible to transform time series into a hypergraph?
I am trying to model some ecological data into hypergraphs.
I have several species, and for each species, I have the quantity data at specific time points. I would like to represent the interactions between these species as higher-order interactions, but I am not sure how to do that.
A possible solution could be to represent each data point as a hypergraph and if two or more species appear in the same data point, I create an hyperedge. Eventually, I would sum up all the hypergraphs and I would find a threshold.
Does anyone have a better idea?
Many thanks for your help and best regards.
